# Pas de tout/toute

Tags: déterminants

Dans le livre Grammaire française (N. Baccus, Librio Mémo) j'ai rencontré la phrase :

> Je ne veux pas de toute cette soupe.

Est-ce interchangeable avec la phrase ci-après ?

> Je ne veux pas du tout cette soupe.

Comment: In Québec the final *t* of this *tout* is pronounced, giving the impression that it's *toute*. (In fact, it can be compressed to [*pantoute*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pantoute).) In "standard" French it's always *tout* — barring, of course, the very different interpretation achieved by reparsing as jlliagre does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non.

- Dans la première phrase, on veut bien une partie de la soupe mais pas la totalité (toute).
- Dans la deuxième, on insiste sur le fait que l'on ne veut pas de soupe, même pas un petit peu. On aurait pu aussi dire: *Je ne veux pas du tout **de** cette soupe*.

Comment: Très bien. Merci !